# Word boundary to use in unicode text for Python regex

Tags: python, regex, unicode

I want to use word boundary in a regex for matching some unicode text. Unicode letters are detected as word boundary in Python regex as here:

```
>>> re.search(r"\by\b","üyü")
<_sre.SRE_Match object at 0x02819E58>

>>> re.search(r"\by\b","ğyğ")
<_sre.SRE_Match object at 0x028250C8>

>>> re.search(r"\by\b","uyu")
>>>
```

What should I do in order to make the word boundary symbol not match unicode letters?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use it the following way:

```
re.search(r'(?u)\by\b', 'üyü')
```

To gain familiarity with flags experiment with the following: (?iLmsux)

As a good read check out Core Python Applications Programming 3rd edition..There is a nice chapter on Regex' in it.

Answer (score 9):

Use [re.UNICODE](http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.UNICODE):

```
>>> re.search(r"\by\b","üyü", re.UNICODE)
>>>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

s = ur"abcd ААБВ"
import re
rx1 = re.compile(ur"(?u)АБВ")
rx2 = re.compile(ur"(?u)АБВ\b")
rx3 = re.compile(ur"(?u)\bАБВ\b")
print rx1.findall(s)
print rx2.findall(s)
print rx3.findall(s)

print re.search(ur'(?u)ривет\b', ur'Привет')
print re.search(ur'(?u)\bривет\b', ur'Привет')
```

Output:

```
[u'\u0410\u0411\u0412']
[u'\u0410\u0411\u0412']
[]
<_sre.SRE_Match object at 0x01F056B0>
None
```